# Getting the Controll.Name of Dynamic Created Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I am currently creating a small application where I create multiple textBox Controlls to a Panel depending on how many the user wants to be created. 
Afterwards I want to get the Text of this Textboxes but for this i do need the Contoll Name. Maybe one of you can tell me how I can find out the controll Names of every created TextBox.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why not set the names of the textboxes explicitly when you create them? Although, I'm not sure why you'd need to access them by name when you don't even know how many there are. Just enumerate the panel's children to get the textboxes. Or store them in an array when you create them and access them via the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you will treat each textbox differently. For example the text value of one textbox will be for first name, the next for last name and so on. So you do not only need the name of the textbox but also do something different for each one. Here is some code where I generate some textboxes in a loop. I give them names and then I add an event handler to them. In the handler I make the decision on what to do with the value entered for the text. You should give your textboxes more descriptive names depending on your needs

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var txtBox = new TextBox();
        txtBox.Name = "TextBox" + i;
        txtBox.TextChanged += TxtBox_TextChanged;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(txtBox);
    }
}

private void TxtBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var txtBox = sender as TextBox;
    string firstName = string.Empty;
    string lastName = string.Empty;
    switch (txtBox.Name)
    {
        case "TextBox1":
            firstName = txtBox.Text;
            break;
        case "TextBox2":
            lastName = txtBox.Text;
            break;
        // more cases here but you get the point...
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code picks `textbox1` from `tableLayoutPanel1`, cast it from Control to `TextBox` and takes `Text` property:

```
string s = ((TextBox)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls["TxtBox1"]).Text;
```

if you need them all, then iterate over textboxes:

```
string[] t = new string[4];
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    t[i] = ((TextBox)tableLayoutPanel1.Controls["TxtBox"+(i+1).ToString()]).Text;
```